# Sqlite Join with 1 million records

Tags: performance, sqlite, query-performance

I have 3 tables:

**Device**: Id, Name.

**Machine**: Id, P1, P2, date_time, IdDevice.

**Parameters**: Id, T, V, I, date_time, IdDevice.

In device there isn't a lot of records. But in the other way, inside Machine and Parameters every minute is inserted a new record. So right now we can find 1M records and the next year we expect 20M records inside of each of this 2 tables.

IdDevice and date_time for both tables are indexed.

How can I improve the performance?

For example for this sentance it's taking 10 min and it isn't done yet.

```
SELECT p.T, p.V, p.I, m.P1, m.P2, p.date_time
FROM Device d 
INNER JOIN Parameters p ON d.ID = p.IdDevice
INNER JOIN Machine m ON d.ID = m.IdDevice
GROUP BY d.ID
ORDER BY p.date_time DESC
```

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: Include the [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](https://sqlite.org/eqp.html) output? Also run [ANALYZE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html) if you haven't, and maybe a [PRAGMA optimize](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_optimize) daily after that to rebuild the stats tables as needed as the DB grows.

Comment: Also what's with that GROUP BY? It'd cause an error on most other databases because you have non-grouped, non-aggregate columns in the select... As it is, sqlite just picks a random row from the group to use instead of erroring out. See https://www.sqlite.org/quirks.html#aggregate_queries_can_contain_non_aggregate_result_columns_that_are_not_in_the_group_by_clause